# Labels on grouped bars in barplot()

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a **barplot with grouped bars**. Is it possible to include a l**abel for each bar** ? Example of plot **without** bar **labels**:

```
test <- structure(c(0.431031856834624, 0.54498742364355, 0.495317895592119,0.341002949852507, 0.40229990800368, 0.328769657724329,0.258600583090379,0.343181818181818, 0.260619469026549), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("2015", "2016", "2017"), c("a", "b", "c")))

barplot(test,ylim=c(0,1),beside=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
p <- barplot(test, ylim=c(0, 1), beside=T)
text(p, test + .05*sign(test), labels=format(round(test, digits=2), nsmall=2))
```

The last line adds the labeling over the bar plots.
p takes the return values of the `barplot()` which are the x-axis bar positions.
In this example this is of the format 3x3 matrix.
`text()` needs then p for his `x=` argument. And for his `y=` argument it needs a slightly offsetted value than its bar plot heights (`test`). `sign()` determines the direction (above or below, `+1` or `-1`) of the bar and `.05` I determined empirically by trying, it is dependent on your values of the table.
So, `x=` and `y=` are the x and y coordinates for the labeling.
And finally, `labels=` determines which text should be printed.
The combination of `format()` and `round()` gives you full control over how many digits you want to display and that the display is absolutely regular in turns of number of digits displayed, which is not, if you use only `round()`.

With `xpd=T` you could determine, whether labeling is allowed to go outside of region or not.
`cex=` could determine the fontsize of the label,
`col=` the colouring and `font=` the font.

alternatively, you can give just `test` for `y=` and determine via `pos=3` that it should be above and `offset=1` how many characterwidths the offset of the text shoul be.

```
p <- barplot(test, ylim=c(0, 1), beside=T)
text(x=p, y=test, pos=3, offset=1, labels=format(round(test, digits=2), nsmall=2))
```

You can find plenty of more instructions by looking into the documentation by

```
?text
# and
?barplot
```

in the R console

Answer (score 0):

You can add a label using `text` function by extending your barplot. You can play with the parameters as you wish. Here is the sample code and its output.

```
x= barplot(test,ylim=c(0,1),beside=T)
text(x, test, labels=test, pos=1, offset=.5, col="red", srt = 90) #srt is used for vertical labels
```

[image]

If you really want to make a better plot, I would recommend `ggplot` as it has several other features like adding a theme to your plots and it is more easy for customizations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to label ever bar's category not it's value you can do something like this

```
allPermutations <- unlist(lapply(colnames(test), function(x) paste(x, rownames(test)) ))

barplot(test,ylim=c(0,1),beside=T, names.arg = allPermutations, las=2)
```

the file line gets all the combinations of categories. The plot call allows you to specify individual values with "names.arg" while las=2 rotates the names so it shows a bit nicer